# Create NativeScript Helloworld project failed

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-cli

I'm trying to create NativeScript "HelloWorld" project. `> ns create hello-world --ng` throwing below error:

**request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@nativescript/template-hello-world-ng/-/template-hello-world-ng-8.0.5.tgz failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate**

While ns doctor shows all good.

```
> ns doctor
    ✔ Getting environment information
    
    No issues were detected.
        ✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
        ✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
        ✔ The Android SDK is installed.
        ✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
        ✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
        ✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
        ✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
        ✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...    
        ✔ Component nativescript has 8.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

I'm not behind any proxy, using Win 10 Operating system and VS Code editor.

Comment: It has been resolved using re-installing Nativescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer to this question myself. After struggling for few days I can able to fix this issue by simply re-installing Nativescript.

Hope this may help someone.